# How to test if directory is hidden in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this loop:

```
  foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in downloadedMessageInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            if (dir.Attributes != FileAttributes.Hidden)
            {
                dir.Delete(true);
            }
        }
```

How can I correctly skip all hidden directories?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In .NET 4.0 you can do:

```
dir.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)
```

Comment: The HasFlags() method is a new addition to .NET 4. It's much easier to use than the old bitwise comparison.

Answer (score 37):

Change your if statement to:

```
if ((dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
```

You need to use the bitmask since Attributes is a flag enum.  It can have multiple values, so hidden folders may be hidden AND another flag.  The above syntax will check for this correctly.

Answer (score 16):

[`Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes.aspx) is a [`Flags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) value, so you need to check if it contains [`FileAttributes.Hidden`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) using a bitwise comparison, like this:

```
if ((dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == 0)
```

Comment: Only problem is when I try evaluate the above, it still by passes... even though the directory is really hidden

Comment: Sorry, thought you were looking _for_ hidden directories, not excluding them.  Fixed above code.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me in VB.Net;

```
If (dir.Attributes.Tostring.Contains("Hidden") Then
    ' File is hidden
Else
    ' File is not hidden
EndIf
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient, use `dir.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)`