# c# check if a directory is hidden?

Tags: c#, directory, file-attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to test if directory is hidden in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288975/how-to-test-if-directory-is-hidden-in-c)

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\test");
if ((dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == (FileAttributes.Hidden)) 
{ 
     //do stuff
}
```

With this if statement i would like to test if the directory is hidden. Although the directory really is hidden, my program doesn't get into the do stuff because only the directory flag of the attributes is set.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Check that the directory is actually hidden, that code worked for me. Also, you don't need parentheses around `FileAttributes.Hidden`.

Comment: You are going to have to figure out how this directory managed to hide itself without the attribute.

Comment: apparently the check works if for c:\test for example but it doesn't for a folder on my desktop

Comment: Okay, sorry to bother you guys. Problem mysteriously solved. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\test");
if ((dir.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != 0)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: if (dir.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)) better