# hidden directory in C#

Tags: c#, directory, console-application

I made a hidden directory in drive F and named it "File".

This code shows it is hidden file : `Console.WriteLine(dc.Attributes);`

But when I use DirectoryInfo Attributes to check if it's a hidden file it won't work.

Here is the code :

```
DirectoryInfo dc = new DirectoryInfo(@"F:\File");
        Console.WriteLine(dc.Attributes);
        if (dc.Attributes == FileAttributes.Hidden)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HIDDEN");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NOT HIDDEN");
        }
```

It writes `NOT HIDDEN`. What should I do with that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288975/how-to-test-if-directory-is-hidden-in-c ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the attributes value is a bitwise combination of multiple attributes.

To test whether the `FileAttributes.Hidden` attribute is set, you need to do this:

```
if ((dc.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden)
```

I would suggest you read about [how bitwise combinations work](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544990/Understand-how-bitwise-operators-work-Csharp-and-V).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .NET 4 and above do :

```
dir.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)
```